# Unit Test with Pandas Dataframe to read *.csv files

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am often vertically concatenating many *.csv files in Pandas. So, everytime I do this, I have to check that all the files I am concatenating have the same number of columns. This became quite cumbersome since I had to figure out a way to ignore the files with more or less columns than what I tell it I need. eg. the first 10 files have 4 columns but then file #11 has 8 columns and file #54 has 7 columns. This means I have to load all files - even the files that have the wrong number of columns. I want to avoid loading those files and then trying to concatenate them vertically - I want to skip them completely.

So, I am trying to write a Unit Test with Pandas that will:
a. check the size of all the *.csv files in some folder
b. ONLY read in the files that have a pre-determined number of columns
c. print a message indicating the naems of the *.csv files have the wrong number of columns

Here is what I have (I am working in the folder C:\Users\Downloads):

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

# Create csv files:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df1.to_csv('test1.csv')
df1.to_csv('test2.csv')

class Conct(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `primes.py`."""

    TEST_INP_DIR = 'C:\Users\Downloads'
    fns = listdir(TEST_INP_DIR)
    t_fn = fn for fn in fns if fn.endswith(".csv") ]
    print t_fn
    dfb = pd.DataFrame()

    def setUp(self):
        for elem in Conct.t_fn:
            print elem
            fle = pd.read_csv(elem)
            try:
                pd.concat([Conct.dfb,fle],axis = 0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=False)
            except IOError:
                print 'Error: unable to concatenate a file with %s columns.' % fle.shape[1]
            self.err_file = fle

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.err_fle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Problem:
I am gettingthis output:

```
['test1.csv', 'test2.csv']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The first print statement works - it is printing a list of *.csv files, as expected. But, for some reason, the second and third print statements do not work.

Also, the concatenation should not have gone through - the second file has 3 columns but the first one has got 4 columns. The IOerror line does not seem to be printing.

How can I use a `Python unittest` to check each of the *.csv files to make sure that they have the same number of columns before concatenation? And how can I print the appropriate error message at the correct time?

Comment: Is this a typo: `df1.to_csv('test1.csv)
df1.to_csv('test2.csv)` shouldn't the path be fully enclosed in single quotes? like this: `df1.to_csv('test1.csv')
df1.to_csv('test2.csv')`

Comment: I'm not sure about this method you are trying to do, but it ought to be pretty easy to accomplish the same thing by using the chunksize keyword for read_csv to create an iterator.  Just read in the first part of the file and if it's the correct size, keep going, but if it's the wrong size, go on to the next file.

Comment: EDChum: Thank you. Corrected the typo.

Comment: @JohnE: I am not sure I understand that `chunksize` keyword from the official documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html). How would that work in the current case? If you have used it in the past, feel free to post a response and I will try it out.

Comment: Yeah, actually ```nrows=1``` is simpler than ```chunksize``` for what you are trying to do.  I sketched out an answer below, see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, instead of chunksize, just read in the first row and count the number of columns, then read and append everything with the correct number of columns.  In short:

```
for f in files:
    test = pd.read_csv( f, nrows=1 )
    if len( test.columns ) == 4:
        df = df.append( pd.read_csv( f ) )
```

Here's the full version:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,4), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,3), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,4), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df1.to_csv('test1.csv',index=False)
df2.to_csv('test2.csv',index=False)
df3.to_csv('test3.csv',index=False)

files = ['test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    test = pd.read_csv( f, nrows=1 )
    if len( test.columns ) == 4:
        df = df.append( pd.read_csv( f ) )

In  [54]: df
Out [54]: 
          A         B         C         D
0  0.308734  0.242331  0.318724  0.121974
1  0.707766  0.791090  0.718285  0.209325
0  0.176465  0.299441  0.998842  0.077458
1  0.875115  0.204614  0.951591  0.154492
```

(**Edit to add**)  Regarding the use of `nrows` for the `test...` line:  The only point of the test line is to read in enough of the CSV so that on the next line we check if it has the right number of columns before reading in.  In this test case, reading in the first row is sufficient to figure out if we have 3 or 4 columns, and it's inefficient to read in more than that, although there is no harm in leaving off the `nrows=1` besides reduced efficiency.

In other cases (e.g. no header row and varying numbers of columns in the data), you might **need** to read in the whole CSV.  In that case, you'd be better off doing it like this:

```
for f in files:
    test = pd.read_csv( f )
    if len( test.columns ) == 4:
        df = df.append( test )
```

The only downside of that way is that you completely read in the datasets with 3 columns that you don't want to keep, but you also don't read in the good datasets twice that way.  So that's definitely a better way if you don't want to use `nrows` at all.  Ultimately, depends on what your actual data looks like as to which way is best for you, of course.

Comment: Read the first *uncommented* row.

Comment: It's not uncommon in csv files to have rows commented out completely, often the first few rows -- look at the paragraph of explanation for the `comment` argument to `pd.read_csv`. So I'd be sure I was checking the first uncommented rows to validate the columns.

Comment: @cphlewis Good point.  I just intended this as a a simpler way to do what the poster was trying to do  based on the sample code. The test read could certainly be expanded to handle more realistic cases.  And the poster never reacted to the answer so who knows?

Comment: well, it's only two days.... anyway, since the theory of SO is a database of answers for everyone else to find, I wanted to put that in.

Comment: @JohnE: You have 3 lines after your `for` statement. The lines I am referring to are `test = pd.read_csv.....pd.read_csv( f ) )`. This is based on `nrows =3` and I am having difficulty understanding the first of the 3 lines - the one that contains `nrows`. Considering that I only have **1** headerline, I am not certain why `nrows=3` is needed. Could you please explain these what this first line is doing and how it might be used if each of the `*.csv` files has only one headerline? (NOTE: The headerline is the same for all the files).

Comment: Continuation of my above comment:  From what I can understand of the Pandas `read_csv()` documentation, `nrows` will only read a few lines of a file, rather than the entire file. I am just really uncomfortable with `nrows` because it doesn't seem to be intuitive as to how it can be used to determine the number of columns. In order to check that the same number of columns are present in all the files, could 1 or 2 row(s) be used instead of `nrows=3`? Apologies if I sound a little frustrated - been playing with this for a while and don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: @W R @WR I added some more to the answer, maybe that will help.  I have to admit I don't understand your concern about ```nrows```.  As you constructed the example, it really doesn't matter, and I can't anticipate what problem you are foreseening on some other dataset.  Note that the test based on ```len(test.columns)``` is just one way you might test things.  I thought it was the simplest way for your example but of course you could use other types of tests as conditions dictate.  You could post a new question with a different example dataset if you have something specific in mind.

Comment: Thank you! Your updated post answers all my questions. It works as I had asked in the original post (question). This is great feature that I now understand. Thanks again.